# Which is better segmentation with paging or paging?

Tags: operating-system

Which is better segmentation with paging or paging alone because internal fragmentation are going to be there in in both ?

Comment: I think you are quite too broad. Try explaining a little bit better your question and if you give an example of what you mean, it might help understand better!

Comment: I read that segmented paging saves space rather than paging but if you divide the segments into pages same number of entries will be made in page table entries as in case of paging .

Comment: Segments have been obsolete since the late 1970's.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, in segmentation the entire process is is divided into different segments like global, code and heap.

While it is true that internal fragmentation is there in both segmentation and paging, segmentation provides a mechanism to prevent page faults as compared to regular paging.

Think of it this way,

Simple paging: Processor just fetches the next pages in the control flow, but does not take into consideration whether those pages work with global data(whether the pages that have them should be loaded). Hence more page faults.

Segmentation with paging: All segments are paged separately and the next items required for each segment is paged. Hence comparatively less page faults.

This is comparable to the data and instruction cache requirements in processors. To answer your question segmentation with paging is better than simple paging, not in terms of internal fragmentation but for performance improvement.